# Error:Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular10 project this comes even though I `import 'rxjs/operator/map';` and `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Service Code is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllPosts(){
    return this.http.get('/posts').map((posts) => {
      return posts;
    });
  }
}
```

How can I overcome this error? My rxjs version is above 6 and angular version is 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pipe your operators.
From [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)

> Note that, for Angular apps, we prefer combining operators with pipes, rather than chaining. Chaining is used in many RxJS examples.

Try:

```js
return this.http.get('/posts').pipe(
    map((posts) => {return posts; }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Http calls are async.

In angular such calls return a Observeble, wich will make the value result accessible via callback, and not directly

Observables in fact do not have a "map" operation.

What you can do is `pipe(map(..))` to transform values. But I assume you want do recieve the Posts as a "pure" value, if you call ``getAllPosts()`.

Mapping is for transforming certain Values and changing the "Observable"-Result-Data.

I would consider the following approach:

```js
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllPosts(): Observable<Posts[]>{
    return this.http.get('/posts');
  }
}
```

And the Component that calls the Authservice:

```js
export class AnyComponent impments OnInit{

  constructor( private auth:AuthService) { }

  public posts: Posts[] = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    auth.getAllPosts().subscribe( (_posts:Post[] => this.posts = _posts);
  }
}
```

I made some assumption about what you want to accomplish.